# Drupal : How to export post from drupal 7 to Excel

Tags: drupal-7

I've inherited a Drupal site. I need to extract the post data only post title and url of it, out of the site to be able to import it into a different system, but I've never used Drupal and the site is live so I need to tread carefully in order to extract the data without affecting the site.

I try use this [Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_export_xls) But canot understan use it, Sow How can i do that. and if any code to export data without modules or views tell me

So, How can export all post from my site that created after 1/1/2014

Comment: Hey you can write sql query to fetch data only if you are not interested in module else module is better option as its configurable :).

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easy with drupal views.

- Download and enable views, views excel import. -
  http://drupal.org/project/views,
  https://www.drupal.org/project/views_export_xls
- Create an new views page (structure - views), set filter criteria for the type of content you like and date created criteria, set format to display fields. Add both title and link as fields (remove
  wrappers if any).
- Once you've completed 1,2 add new display to same view called Feed,
  following from the module doc:

Add a new "Feed" display to your view.
Change its style to "XLS file"
Configure the options (such as name, quote, etc.).
Give it a path in the Feed settings such as "path/to/xls".
Optionally, you can choose to attach this to another of your displays by updating the "Attach to:" option in feed settings.

Once you've finished, navigate to the path.